# Flutter web project with javascript modules that use requireJS (Monaco editor in Flutter web)

Tags: flutter, requirejs, monaco-editor

I'm trying to use the [Monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) in Flutter Web.

The simplest way that I see is to sync load all the resources [example](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/browser-script-editor/index.html).

Here's a stand alone html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            data-name="vs/editor/editor.main"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css"
        />

    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "codicon",
        src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon.ttf") format("truetype")
      }
    </style>
    <title>Monaco</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Monaco Editor Sync Loading Sample</h2>
    <div id="code" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid grey"></div>

    <script>
      var require = { paths: { vs: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs" } };
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>

    <script>
      var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("code"), {
        value:  ['function x() {', '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");', '}'].join('\n'),
        language: "javascript",
        additionalCssClassName: "code"
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My question is: How do I modify the `index.html` file of the sample Flutter Web project, so I can load all the required assets?  There seems to be an issue with the line

```js
      var require = { paths: { vs: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.44.0/min/vs" } };
```

as the flutter build never finishes (gets stuck somewhere.)  I see that Flutter itself uses requirejs and there may be a conflict that I don't know how to resolve.

If you know how to do this, please post a Fluter Web `index.html` file that loads all the js required files for the editor.

Thank you,
T

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Hua777/flutter_monaco_editor

I have roughly completed the flutter version of monaco editor.

But it's not perfect yet, I hope it helps.

**how does it work**

```dart
  static Future<void> _waitForGetting() async {
    if (_monaco == null) {
      print('[monaco] getting...');
      return Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 1),
        () {
          return _waitForGetting();
        },
      );
    }
  }

  static Future<void> load() async {
    print('[monaco] preparing');
    final NodeValidatorBuilder htmlValidator = NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
      ..allowElement('link', attributes: ['rel', 'href', 'data-name'])
      ..allowElement('script', attributes: ['src']);
    (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] as HtmlElement).insertAdjacentHtml(
      'afterBegin',
      '''
<link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="/vs/editor/editor.main.css">
<script src="/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script src="/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
<script src="/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
  ''',
      validator: htmlValidator,
    );
    print('[monaco] loading');
    await _waitForGetting();
    print('[monaco] loaded');
  }
```

`load` function import monaco js.

`_waitForGetting` function make sure monaco loads successfully.

you just need to call `load` in `main` function.

**next step**

```dart
var monaco = context['monaco'];
```

you can use monaco like js.